# Hibernate 4 + Spring 3.2 + Transaction : One Service, Several Dao , One Method

Tags: spring, hibernate, service, transactions, dao

I'm a beginner in hibernate 4 & Spring 3.2 stuffs.
I have read some tutorials and discussion on stack but i don't find a clear answer to my questions. And i think the best way to understand is to ask and share knowledges !

Here we go!
So you create each time a Pojo, a Dao , a Service class, with methods annotated transactionnal. That's ok. I'm using Sessionfactory to handle my transaction. I'm looking for good practices.

1-  If you want to use Delete Method and Save Method from the **same** Service, how will you do to make it works in a same transaction. When i look at the log, each method are executed in different transactions.

This SampleServiceImpl:

```
    @Transactional
    public void save(Sample sample){

        sampleDao.save(sample);
    }
    @Transactional
    public void delete(Sample sample){

        sampleDao.delete(sample);
    }

// A solution could be that , but not very clean...there should be an another way, no?

        @Transactional
        public void action(Sample sample){

        sampleDao.save(sample);

        sampleDao.delete(sample);
    }
```

2-  If you want to use Delete Method and Save Method from **different** Services class, how will you do to make it works in a same transaction. Because each method in each service class is handled by a Transactionnal annotation. Do you create a global Service calling all subservice in one method annoted Transactional

```
    SampleServiceImpl:

    @Transactional
    public void save(Sample sample){

        sampleDao.save(sample);
    }

        ParcicipantServiceImpl
        @Transactional 
        public void save(Participant participant){

         participantDao.save(participant);
    }

// A solution could be that , but not very clean...there should be an another way, no?
        GlobalServiceImpl

        @Transactional 
        public void save(Participant participant,Sample sample){

         participantDao.save(participant);
                 sampleDao.save(sample);
    }
```

3-  And the last question but not the least .If you want to use several Methods from severals service in one global transaction. Imagine you want to fill up 5 or more table in one execution of a standalone program. How is it possible because each Service to have his proper transactional method, so each time you called this method, there is a transaction.

a- I have successfully arrive to fill up two tables in a sample transaction using Mkyong tutorial and cascade property in the mapping. So i see how to make it works for one table directly joined to one another or more tables.
b- But if you have a 3 tables Participant -> Samples -> Derived Products. How will you fill up the three tables in a same transaction.

I don't know if i'm clear. But i would appreciated some help or example on that from advanced users.
Thanks a lot for you time.

Answer (score 1):

1. Your solution is fine, maybe this works if you want to using nested transactional methods(note I saw this solution couple days ago and didn't test it):

   < tx:annotation-driven mode="aspectj" / >
   < context:load-time-weaver aspectj-weaving="on"/ >

```
    
    @Transactional
    public void action(Sample sample){
        save(sample);
        delete(sample);
    }
```

1. Transaction should propagate.

GlobalServiceImpl

```
@Transactional 
public void save(Participant participant,Sample sample){
     participantDao.save(participant);
     sampleServiceImpl.save(sample); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The approch you are following is cleaner approch,

ServiceOpjects are ment to contain business logic. Hence they will always manuplate through data objects. 
What we do in practise is create a another layer that uses dataObjects and and other functional call of same layer. Then this all business layer is called via service layer having annotation `@transactional`.

Can you please mention why you think this approch is dirty??

Comment: I don't like the idea you make method with sequence of actions (delete, save,update, select by, ...). I would like to have a way to keep unique method separate save/delete/update/select/other and to organize them in my Main class in the order i want in a global transaction. I dont want to have to implement each time a method with the sequencial actions .Because in fact , you will have to code a method in a parentService calling Child services . ParentService have no sense,just it is convenient to handle you transac . I think you could do it directly in the main without creating a globalservice

Comment: may be that depends on need. Fr eg when user is created in our product we need to insert in 14 tables and delete from 1 ... their is no other way of doing it ...

Comment: And we allways want to call It addUser inspite so that it has business meaning for same